# How does one implement C# code-first computed-column auto-update

Tags: c#, code-first, calculated-columns, auto-update

I have a C# Entity Framework code-first Computed-column issue that I cannot solve by viewing any of the other solutions I've found on the web.
I believe this is because my issue has to do with a calculation
that must be made after a row is created.

Consider this simplified example (code-first):

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key] public long Id;
    public int ExpectedChildCount { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public int ActualChildCount { get; private set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Child
{
    [Key]  public long Id;  
    public long ParentId { get; set; }  // FK
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

Doing "Add-Migration ChildCountComputed" yields the following, 
in which I modified the Up() method:

```
public partial class ChildCountComputed : DbMigration
{
        public override void Up()
        {
            //AlterColumn("Parent", "ActualChildCount", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
            Sql("UPDATE Parent SET Parent.ActualChildCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Child c WHERE c.ParentId = Parent.Id)" );

        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            AlterColumn("dbo.ServerArchive", "ActualObjectInstanceCount", c => c.Int(nullable: false));
        }
}
```

I confirmed that the UPDATE command is valid and does what is expected 
(update the Parent.ActualChildCount for all *already exisiting* Parent rows)
when run from, say, LINQPad.

However, when a Program creates a Parent for the first time, it may have no 
Children. Later, they get added. But the Parent.ActualChildCount never gets
auto updated.

How can I get that column (Parent.ActualChildCount) to be auto-updatated 
whenever Children are added to a Parent?

Am I incorrect in thinking it can be done via a Computed column?

In addition, I wonder if the 'ActualChildCount.get()' method needs to do 
something? (but that would defeat the purpose of a Computed column, right?)

Comment: It's not clear what you need, can you show some use-case. EF can't automagicaly monitor any change in DB and push them to model instances (which commonly may be already detached from DBContext).

Comment: Thinking more about it, this is the issue I am trying to address: "when a Child is added, increment the associated Parent.ActualChildCount column. The Parent would be identified by the Child.ParentId field and/or the associated Parent class reference in the Child class. I do not where to do this? In the Migration's Up() method? Somewhere else?

Comment: @vasily.sib - I cannot seem to edit my previous reply to your comment (to add your handle and fix a typo). So I am doing it in this comment. In my previous comment I meant to say: "I do not *KNOW* where to do this"

Comment: Just for closure, this is what ended up working for me....

DropColumn("dbo.Parent", "ActualChildCount");
Sql(_createFunctionScript);
Sql("alter table dbo.Parent ADD ActualChildCount AS [dbo].[ComputeActualChildCount]([Id])");

pubic readonly string _createFunctionScript = string.Concat(
"CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ComputeActualChildCount] ",
"( \@id bigint ) ", "RETURNS INT ",
"AS ",
"BEGIN ",
"DECLARE \@retValue INT; ",
"SELECT \@retValue = (Select COUNT(*) FrOM dbo.Child c WHERE c.ParentId =\ @id ); ",
"RETURN COALESCE(\@retValue, 0);", "END" );

Remove the '\' from the at chars

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question. Long code blocks in comments are not readable.